# Python Code to create a ppt which has two images in a slide?

Tags: python

When Iam running the code attached no presentation is being opened as I am new to python I dont understand where I am doing wrong and I have the images with names eagle_1 and hawk_1 in the respective folder

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.util import Inches
from glob import glob
import os

img_path = 'D:/Pyhtoncheck'
def iter_image_pairs():
    prs = Presentation()
    content_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
    eagles, hawks = [], []
    for image_path in glob.glob(img_path + '/*.png'):
        if "eagle" in image_path:
            eagles.append(image_path)
        elif "hawk" in image_path:
            hawks.append(image_path)
    for pair in zip(eagles, hawks):
        yield pair
for eagle, hawk in iter_image_pairs():
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(content_slide_layout)   
    slide.shapes.add_picture(eagle, left=Inches(0), top=Inches(0), width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3))
    slide.shapes.add_picture(hawk, left=Inches(2), top=Inches(2), width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3))
prs.save("eagle_hawk.pptx") 
os.startfile("eagle_hawk.pptx")
```

Comment: may i suggest you to break down the elephant in smaller bites, start checking why the presentation does not open in the first place (eg. you have the modules and the right env and such) with a simple pres = Presentation()

and then let us know the exact error . keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @carlo's comment. Hi pavankonchada, you'd better break down the elephant in small bites and debug them step by step by yourself which can make you understand the code better.

Try this below:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.util import Inches
from glob import glob

img_path = 'D:/Pyhtoncheck'
def iter_image_pairs():
    eagles, hawks = [], []
    for image_path in glob(img_path + '/*.png'):
        if "eagle" in image_path:
            eagles.append(image_path)
        if "hawk" in image_path:
            hawks.append(image_path)
    for pair in zip(eagles, hawks):
        yield pair

prs = Presentation()
content_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
for eagles, hawks in iter_image_pairs():
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(content_slide_layout)
    slide.shapes.add_picture(eagles, left=Inches(0), top=Inches(0), width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3))
    slide.shapes.add_picture(hawks, left=Inches(2), top=Inches(2), width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3))
prs.save("eagle_hawk.pptx")
```

I tested it on my notebook laptop, and it worked well. Hope it helps. I eliminate the last line in yours and make some adjustments according to the error. If you have any questions about the code above, plz let me know.